# Why if rotate my android phone my application gui settings has dropped?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

For example, I have write GUI. I have a SeekBar, I change the progress but if I rotate android phone the progress is dropped as default. Why it's happend and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because androids reloads the activity when the screen is rotated. You can disable the rotaion by adding android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the element in the manifest or landscape.

Or you will need to store the activity's state elsewhere and onload of the activity, set the values from your store.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Activity objects are re-created whenever the orientation changes.

Store the progress somewhere else.